How to fetch application.yml values by querying in xslt file?
I have an application.yml file with a static value,
example x: 1, y: 2
and an xslt file in the main/resource folder.
I want to fetch the values X and Y values in xslt file by using xsl: select query.
I have tried fetching data by adding xmls f:"function"
<xsl:variable name="properties" select"unparsed-text('.properties')" as="xs:string"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="main">
    <xsl:value-of select="f:getProperty('language')"/>
  </xsl:template>

But I ran into a problem:

Error at char 26 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 25 column 59 of responseV3.xslt:
XPST0008: Variable $IsRelatedInstance has not been declared (or its declaration is
not in scope)

Please make a suggestion.

Please show the content of  responseV3.xslt

assume as responseV3.xslt :
abs:
xslt:
IsRelatedInstance: 1
Creator: NetInterface
IsModified: 0
MessageFields: Original
X1: SFXXXX
Intv: Trans
Reporting: Interface

Take a look at your error-message

I spent two days finding the error issue but not able to resolve.

You should really find the file: responseV3.xslt

yes I am able to find the responseV3.xslt but after transforming my req.xml to xslt response some value are static in response. So am trying to keep the static value in application.yml file and querying from xslt file to fetch the static value.
